# KeyListener not working on my object

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

I'm trying to make a box move by using arrow keys, but I just can't seem to make it respond to my keys :/. I watched a couple of tutorials to make this, and I don't really see why my code doesn't work.

Basically I'm trying to make the box behave like in the classic ping pong game, except that it's at the bottom and it moves in X axis only.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could spot why my box doesn't respond to my key events =)
I have 2 classes, the main and the class that contains the "player", which is the box.

Main:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Main extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    Player player;

    Main() {
        player = new Player();
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public void update() {

        player.move();    
        this.repaint(); //runs the paint method on the object
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        player.paint(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int width = 800;
        int height = 600;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pinball"); //create a new window and set title on window
        frame.setSize(width, height); //set size of window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //set the window to close when the cross in the corner is pressed
        Main m = new Main(width,height-22); //-22 to account for menubar height //create a new object and runs constructor for initial setup of the program
        frame.add(m); //add the content of the object to the window
        frame.setVisible(true); //make the window visible

        while (true) { //keep running a loop
            //each time the loop is run do
            m.update(); //run the update method on the object
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10); //stops this part of the program for 10 milliseconds to avoid the loop locking everything. Now the screen has time to update content etc.
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            player.setRight(true);
        }
        else if(code==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            player.setLeft(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Player:

```
package com.company;


import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by John on 13/03/2015.
 */
public class Player {
private Boolean left = false, right = false;
    int xPos=200;     
    Player() {

    }


    public void move(){
        if(left){
            xPos-=2;
        }

        else if(right){
            xPos+=2;
        }
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(xPos,500,20,20);
    }

    public void setLeft(Boolean b){
        left=b;
    }

    public void setRight(Boolean b){
        right=b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Much better to use Key Bindings, but for KeyListener, the JPanel must first be made focusable for a request focus request to work.

Comment: edit: I actually got it to work :D